# Use of red envelopes?

Tags: crossy-road

So I was playing crossy road and I encounter this when playing as Xi:

[image]
 This is pretty crafty, considering he is a Chinese dragon. But are there any uses for these red envelopes, or are they just there for decoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get a mystery character by getting about 20 red envelopes. It is one of the new mystery characters

Comment: 20 red envelopes in one round?

Comment: It could be in multiple rounds, you don't need to collect them all at once.